# Changing self-hosted Omnibus Gitlab Pages URL scheme

Tags: self-hosting, gitlab-omnibus

Is there a way to change a self-hosted Omnibus Gitlab Pages URL scheme ?

from: `<namespace>.pages.<custom domain>.com/<project_slug>`
to:   `pages.<custom domain>.com/<namespace>/<project_slug>`

Gitlab Pages' auto generated cert does not have a wild card for subdomains, it would be much easier if I could just change the URL Scheme.

Any solutions, tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.